# Dynamically loading and unloading 2 qml files from cpp

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qqmlapplicationengine

I have requirement to launch 2 different Qml files "mainwindow.qml" and "basic.qml" ,wheras both are independent of each other.

Initially i need to launch qml window based on flag bSettingMainWindow, based on this i will be launching any one of the qml file.

After launching I need to switch between these 2 qml files anytime. It should be like loading and unloading of "mainwindow.qml" and "basic.qml", based on the user action.
Since because memory concern , i need load any of them at a time. and i dont want to play with visible true or false.

whereas from this below code I can able to load any one of the qml file based on the flag bSettingMainWindow. and also after loading
i can able to switch to another qml file window.

Assume first I have launched in Mainwindow.qml then i clicked the mouse button over Rectangle of mainwindow.qml and moved to basic.qml and now if i click on the Rectangle of basic.qml it is not
switching to mainwindow.qml.
and vice versa.
**Only one time i can able to switch b/w these 2 . I want to switch multiple times.**
Below is the code , requesting to please provide your answers

```
//** windowLoader.hpp   **//
class WindowLoader : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    QQmlApplicationEngine loadQMlEngine;

public:
    explicit WindowLoader(QObject * parent = 0);
    void loadWindow();


public slots:
    void loadMainWindow();
    void loadBasicWindow();
    void connectToMain(QObject *object = nullptr, const QUrl &url = QUrl(""));
    void connectToBasic(QObject *object = nullptr, const QUrl &url = QUrl(""));

    private:
};

//** windowLoader.cpp   **//
WindowLoader::WindowLoader(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {

}

void WindowLoader::loadWindow()  {
    if(bSettingMainWindow){ //this will be from a internal flag, this check is only one time during launch
        connect(&loadQMlEngine,SIGNAL(objectCreated(QObject *, const QUrl &)),this,SLOT(connectToBasic(QObject *, const QUrl &)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
        loadQMlEngine.rootContext()->setContextProperty( "interface", m_interface );
        loadQMlEngine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Qml/mainWindow.qml")));
    } else {
        connect(&loadQMlEngine,SIGNAL(objectCreated(QObject *, const QUrl &)),this,SLOT(connectToMain(QObject *, const QUrl &)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
        loadQMlEngine.rootContext()->setContextProperty( "interface", m_interface );
        loadQMlEngine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Qml/basic.qml")));     
    }
}

void WindowLoader::connectToBasic(QObject *object, const QUrl &url) {
    if(object){
        connect(object, SIGNAL(switchToBasicSignal()), this, SLOT(loadBasicWindow()));
    }
}

void WindowLoader::connectToMain(QObject *object, const QUrl &url) {
    if(object){
        connect(object, SIGNAL(switchToMainSignal()), this, SLOT(loadMainWindow()));
    }
}

void WindowLoader::loadBasicWindow() {
    loadQMlEngine.rootObjects()[0]->deleteLater();
    loadQMlEngine.destroyed();

    loadQMlEngine.rootContext()->setContextProperty( "interface", m_interface );
    loadQMlEngine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Qml/basic.qml")));
}

void WindowLoader::loadMainWindow() {
    loadQMlEngine.rootObjects()[0]->deleteLater();
    loadQMlEngine.destroyed();

    loadQMlEngine.rootContext()->setContextProperty( "interface", m_interface );
    loadQMlEngine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Qml/mainWindow.qml")));

}


//** main.cpp **//
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    WindowLoader root;
    root.loadWindow();
    return app.exec();
}



// ** mainWindow.qml **//
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1200
    height: 800
    title: qsTr("MainWindow")

    signal switchToBasicSignal()

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                switchToBasicSignal()
            }
        }
    }
}

//** basic.qml **//
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("basic")

    signal switchToMainSignal()

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                switchToMainSignal()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Loading and Unloading of the complete window will not give a good user experience. If you have memory concerns and don't want to use visibility property you can try with [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) concepts.

I have tried the below sample code it works. Based on the bool flag I tried to switch between the windows. Please check the sample attached below. I hope this helps to solve your issue.

```
/* main.cpp */
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "backend.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Backend backend(&engine);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend", &backend);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

---

```
/* backend.h */
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QObject>

class QQmlApplicationEngine;
class Backend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Backend(QQmlApplicationEngine *engine, QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE void changeWindow();

private:
    QQmlApplicationEngine *_engine = nullptr;
    bool _main = true;
};

#endif // BACKEND_H
```

---

```
/*backend.cpp*/
#include "backend.h"
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWindow>

Backend::Backend(QQmlApplicationEngine *engine, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    _engine = engine;
}

void Backend::changeWindow()
{
    QObject *qObject = _engine->rootObjects().first();
    Q_ASSERT( qObject != NULL );

    QQuickWindow* mainWindow = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(qObject);
    Q_ASSERT( mainWindow );

    _main = !_main;
    if (_main)
    {
        _engine->load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    } else
    {
        _engine->load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/samplewindow.qml")));
    }
    mainWindow->close();
    qObject->deleteLater();
}
```

---

```
/* main.qml */
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: backend.changeWindow()
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("main window")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

---

```
/* samplewindow.qml */
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: backend.changeWindow()
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("sample window")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its so easy in QML.!!! You dont need to create your own window loader as QML has already Loader. consider this sample. Hope this will work for you.

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "backendcppclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    BackendCPPClass backendCPPClass; /// create instance of backend class.
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend", &backendCPPClass); /// Set context propert so that we can access in QML.

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Loader {
        id: windowLoader
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: backend.bSettingMainWindow ? "qrc:/mainwindow.qml" : "qrc:/basic.qml"
    }
}
```

qml.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>basic.qml</file>
        <file>mainwindow.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

backendcppclass.h

```
#ifndef BACKENDCPPCLASS_H
#define BACKENDCPPCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class BackendCPPClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit BackendCPPClass(QObject *parent = nullptr) {};
    Q_PROPERTY(MEMBER bSettingMainWindow NOTIFY bSettingMainWindowChanged)

signals:
    void bSettingMainWindowChanged();

private:
    bool bSettingMainWindow = false;

};

#endif // BACKENDCPPCLASS_H
```

backendcppclass.cpp

```
#include "backendcppclass.h"

BackendCPPClass::BackendCPPClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    /// update any logic to change the variable bSettingMainWindow.
    /// QML will automatically validate it.
    bSettingMainWindow = true;
    emit bSettingMainWindowChanged();
}
```

And Basic.qml and mainwindow.qml can be ur custom specific qmls.